# React native Camera Kit continuously scan Qr code with mutltiple callbacks onReadCode

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I need to integrate the QR code scanner for my project with react native, I'm using the plugin react-native-camera-kit, this plugin supports QR and Bar code scan but when i scan the code it continuously scan the code and call back the function onReadCode={()=>} the continuously. I need to remove the camera from QR code to stop it.

is that any way to scan the QR code only once.

```
<Camera
 showFrame={true}
 laserColor={Colors.green}
 frameColor="white"
 onReadCode={(event: any) => {
 console.log("event=>", event?.nativeEvent.codeStringValue)
 }}
 scanBarcode={true}
 style={{flex: 1}}
 />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a state and update it once the code is scanned. You can either use the state value to change the prop value `scanBarcode` or you can completely remove the `<Camera .../>` and render something else like the content of the code.

Example 1: This will stop the barcode scanning once it is scanned until you again set the state to true.

```
const [doScanBarcode, setDoScanBarcode] = useState(true);//add this state
.
.
.
<Camera
 showFrame={true}
 laserColor={Colors.green}
 frameColor="white"
 onReadCode={(event: any) => {
   setDoScanBarcode(false);//update the state here
   console.log("event=>", event?.nativeEvent.codeStringValue)
 }}
 scanBarcode={doScanBarcode}//use the state here
 style={{flex: 1}}
/>
```

Example 2: This will render based on the condition so once the code is scanned it will close the camera and show some other content like a message which says the code is scanned.

```
const [renderScanner, setRenderScanner] = useState(true);//add this state
.
.
.
<>
 {
  renderScanner ?
   <Camera
     showFrame={true}
     laserColor={Colors.green}
     frameColor="white"
     onReadCode={(event: any) => {
       setRenderScanner(false);//update state here
       console.log("event=>", event?.nativeEvent.codeStringValue)
     }}
     scanBarcode={true}
     style={{flex: 1}}
  /> :
  <Text>The code is scanned</Text>
 }
</>
```

Make sure to style it properly and import the necessary things.

Happy Coding :)